# If não está funcionando corretamente

Tags: java, if

Olá, pessoal. Tudo bem? Então, eu gostaria de tirar uma duvida.
Eu criei o seguinte codigo:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        String Resposta = "";
        System.out.println("Digite a Combinação correta");
         System.out.println("L, M, N, B");
         System.out.println("Q, S, R, P");
         System.out.println("D, G, H, V");
         Resposta = entrada.nextLine();
         System.out.println(Resposta);
                 if(Resposta == "Floripa"){
            System.out.println("Show! Sou de Floripa");
        }
 

    }
}
```

o problema é o seguinte, quando eu digito Floripa, a variavel muda o valor pra floripa, porem mesmo assim o if não funciona

Answer (score 0):

Para comparar *Strings* em Java, é necessário usar a função *equals*, e não o operador *==*. Para funcionar, faça:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main { public static void main(String[] args) { Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

    String Resposta = "";
    System.out.println("Digite a Combinação correta");
     System.out.println("L, M, N, B");
     System.out.println("Q, S, R, P");
     System.out.println("D, G, H, V");
     Resposta = entrada.nextLine();
     System.out.println(Resposta);
             if(Resposta.equals("Floripa")){
        System.out.println("Show! Sou de Floripa");
    }


}
}
```